# Hibernate returns PersistenceBag or PersistenceSet instead List and Set

Tags: java, hibernate

Ok, table has primary key and unique index for one column.
I used method findAll() of JpaRepository
I need natural list, what can i do to decide this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[PersistentBag](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/) is a `List`.

[PersistentSet](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/collection/internal/PersistentSet.html) is a `Set`.

So you don't have a problem.

Comment: If i dont have problem, i dont ask here. this collection is trasfered to GWT and it dont khow about collections of hibernate thats why i need simple list or set

Comment: Your question is quite unclear and does not indicate something like this. Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] and details of what you expect to happen vs. what actually happens. If there are exceptions thrown please also provide the full stacktraces and don't forget the version information of the frameworks in use. All of this helps others helping you and increases chance to get a useful answer.